# Elemento personalizado Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Como posso fazer um elemento personalizado no aspx que herde **`DropDownList`**?

Gostaria que o elemento ficasse dessa forma quando eu chamá-lo:

`<componente:DropPersonalizado runat="server" id=""></componente:DropPersonalizado>`

Comment: Seria um UserControl?

Comment: Sim @Cezar, seria um user control

Comment: Entendi, você tem mais alguma informação pertinente a fazer algo personalizado, o que vai mudar do original oferecido pela toolbar do que você quer personalizar ??? tem alguma coisa especifica !!! se sim coloque como complemento no seu questionamento !!!

Comment: Cara, no momento eu preciso só disso mesmo. O resto quero tentar fazer sozinho. :D Obrigado pela atencao

Answer (score 0):

Crie um User Control da seguinte forma: Clique no seu projeto e adicione um novo item referente a imagem logo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após colocar o seu nome ele vai abrir um `design` e um `code` referente a esse `UserControl` e você pode adicionar os elementos que tu precisar na construção de algo particular.

**Criação:**

*Coloquei um Panel e um DropDownList dessa maneira:*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WUCDropDownList.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WUCDropDownList" %>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelDrop" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

*Em seu código fiz alguns configurações por exemplo de tamanho, como demostrado no código abaixo:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WUCDropDownList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public Unit Width
        {
            get
            {
                return DropDownList1.Width;
            }
            set
            {
                DropDownList1.Width = value;
                PanelDrop.Width = value;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Porque?**
*Quando eu colocar esse componente na tela eu vou ter acesso publico a essa configuração e com isso posso mudar o tamanho que será renderizado na tela.*

Abra a sua página em Modo Design (Exemplo: *default.aspx*) e arraste o componente criado no local desejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nas suas propriedades vai aparecer aquele configuração de tamanho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Obs:* **Qualquer propriedade, evento ou configuração deve ser implementado no `Código` `do User Control`**